# How to implement email for your apps in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, email

I tried to implement 'mail composer' (sample code from dev) to my apps. They are a lot of hard coded in the sample code. For example: sent to recipient - first@example.com. I want to leave it blank like `@""`, however it automatically prefix comma in front of the email address. I also have other concern, based on apple DEV readme.txt, `launchMailAppOnDevice` will be triggered if `displayComposerSheet` is failed. Should I replace all hardcoded in `launchMailAppOnDevice` and how to do it?
Please advise.

```
-(IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender
{
        // This sample can run on devices running iPhone OS 2.0 or later  
        // The MFMailComposeViewController class is only available in iPhone OS 3.0 or later. 
        // So, we must verify the existence of the above class and provide a workaround for devices running 
        // earlier versions of the iPhone OS. 
        // We display an email composition interface if MFMailComposeViewController exists and the device can send emails.
        // We launch the Mail application on the device, otherwise.

        Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
        if (mailClass != nil)
        {
                // We must always check whether the current device is configured for sending emails
                if ([mailClass canSendMail])
                {
                        [self displayComposerSheet];
                }
                else
                {
                        [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
                }
        }
        else
        {
                [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
        }
}


// Displays an email composition interface inside the application. Populates all the Mail fields. 

-(void)displayComposerSheet 

{
        MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [picker setSubject:@"Visit my new apps in app store!"];


        // Set up recipients
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 


        [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

        //Replace the email body with the content from my textview

        [picker setMessageBody:TextView.text isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    [picker release];
}


// Launches the Mail application on the device.

-(void)launchMailAppOnDevice
{
        NSString *recipients = @"mailto:first@example.com?cc=second@example.com,third@example.com&subject=Hello from California!";
        NSString *body = @"&body=It is raining in sunny California!";

        NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];
        email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the mail class in your .h files

Comment: Yep. I only want know how to leave blank the toRecipients variable?

NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"];

If I do something like this, it will prefix comma (,) to the email address when the user input the email address.

NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@""];

Comment: I add 's' after object and it works.

NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil];

Answer (score 0):

Replace your hard coded values in 
"launchMailAppOnDevice".. it works for mine